# emberjs - Pass dynamic arguments to the component helper

Tags: ember.js

How can I pass dynamic arguments to the component helper.

In production, I am iterating over a json hash that will render different components with different attrs each time.

I have a scaled down example in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tumope/edit?html,js,output).

I am returning this json hash:

```
  columns: Ember.computed('people.[]', function() {
    return this.get('people').map(function(person){
      return {
        component: 'x-person',
        attrs: {
          person: person
        }
      };
    });
  })
```

That I then iterate over and try and pass the arguments into the component:

```
{{#each columns as |column|}}
  {{component column.component column.attrs}}
{{/each}}
```

The component is getting created but the attributes are not set.

How can I properly pass the arguments to the component helper?

Answer (score 6):

If you want more flexibility like not having to update the way each attr is used in the dynamic component, I suggest this:

**Create an initializer to extend Ember.Component**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var Component = {

  loadAttrsHash: Ember.on('didReceiveAttrs',function(attrs){

    if(this.get('attrsHash')){

      let hash = this.get('attrsHash');

      Object.keys(hash).forEach(key=>{
        this.set(key,hash[key]);
      });

    }

  }),

};

export function initialize(/* application */) {
  Ember.Component = Ember.Component.extend(Component);
}

export default {
  name: 'component',
  initialize
};
```

**Then you can create dynamic components with an attrs hash**

```
{#each columns as |column|}}
  {{component column.component attrsHash=column.model}}
{{/each}}
```

Then you can access attrsHash.person, simply with {{person}} in the child component just as if it was passed directly.

This way, the component is more durable as it can be used with direct attributes as well as `attrsHash`, and should update whenever attrsHash changes.

Answer (score 3):

You have to follow some convention to pass all data to dynamic components using model property.

Columns:

```
  columns: Ember.computed('people.[]', function() {
    return this.get('people').map(function(person){
      return {
        component: 'x-person',
        model: {
          person: person
        }
      };
    });
  })
```

Template:

```
{#each columns as |column|}}
  {{component column.component model=column.model}}
{{/each}}
```

And in all components that are dynamically created you should access properties via `model` attribute passed to component. So, if something were `color` before it should now become `model.color` etc.